# how to add new UTF-8 words to Hunspell's user custom dictionary?

Tags: ispell, flyspell, utf-8, hunspell

How do I set up Hunspell so that I can add new UTF-8 words (e.g. "Rúdi") to my user local dictionary?

I have a function that allows me to add new words to my local dictionary. It works for adding new words that don't contain UTF-8 characters. But if a word contains a UTF-8 character, Flyspell doesn't remember that the newly added word is correctly spelled.

Here's my setup:

```
(executable-find "hunspell") 
(setq-default ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(setq ispell-really-hunspell t) 
(setq flyspell-default-dictionary "en_US")

(setq ispell-dictionary "en_US")
(setq ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/hunspell")
(setenv "DICTIONARY" "en_US")


(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(eval-after-load "ispell"
  '(progn (defun ispell-get-coding-system () 'utf-8)))

(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist '(("en_US" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil nil nil utf-8))) 

(setq ispell-extra-args '("-d en_US"))

(flyspell-mode-on)

(defun add-word-to-personal-dictionary ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-location (point))
        (word (flyspell-get-word)))
    (when (consp word)
      (flyspell-do-correct 'save nil (car word) current-location (cadr word) (caddr word) current-location))))
```

If it matters, I'm running Hunspell 1.3.3 on OSX Yosemite.

Comment: A small thing: you probably wanted 
`(setq-default ispell-program-name (executable-find "hunspell"))` `executable-find`, if successful, has no side effects, so in your case it doesn't make sense to call it the way you did.

Comment: @wvxvw Wow, thank you. So like this? https://gist.github.com/incandescentman/00e1be81877514983884 Aside from that does everything look right?

Comment: Yup, like that, and, to my untrained eye it does look alright :)

Comment: Thanks! By the way, do you know how I can view the list of the words I've added to my local dictionary?

Comment: I use `aspell` so I don't know where `hunspell` keeps its personal dictionary, but judging from `aspell` personal dictionary location I'd be looking in the home directory for a file with a `.dic` suffix. (The `aspell` dictionary would normally be something like `~/.aspell.en.pws`). Also, you can run `hunspell -D` to ask it to show all known dictionaries, yours will be one of those).

Comment: Thank you! It was at `~/.hunspell_en_US`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that in my dictionary file, en_US.aff, the first line incorrectly said `SET UTF8`. I corrected it to read `SET UTF-8`